# wxLog Timestamp 5 hours in the past

Tags: wxwidgets

I just upgraded a legacy app from wxWidgets 2.8.x to 2.9.3

The log timestamps are now 5 hours in the past!

[image]

This screenshot was taken at 1:40PM in EST, as shown in the taskbar clock display.

I wouldn't mind so much if the timestamp was UTC, but it seems to be using a timezone somewhere in the Pacific.

How can I alter this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14148 seems to be experiencing the same problem. See if you can get any help on that issue.

As suggested by a careful reading of the discussion on that ticket, this is a bug in wxWidgets v2.9.3, fixed in v2.9.4.